# Automatic updates from Ubuntu 16.04 or 17.10 from terminal

Tags: upgrade, updates, cron

How can I manage automatic updates for servers?

I try e.g. with `crontab -e` following:

## **System Update (each week at 6am)**

```
 0 6 * * 1 date  >/root/log/update.log              
   1 6 * * 1 apt-get update -y   2>>/root/log/update.log
  10 6 * * 1 apt-get upgrade -y  2>>/root/log/update.log
  20 6 * * 1 apt-get dist-upgrade -y 2>>/root/log/update.log
```

But I'm sure there is a better solution.
I have see the cron-apt wich is installed with `apt-get install cron-apt` according to this article:

https://debian-administration.org/article/162/A_short_introduction_to_cron-apt

But I don't really understand how to make it.
Thanks for your time and answers.

Comment: "better solution"? But you haven't said what your complaint is? Why not put all 3 commands in a `bash` script, and execute that via `cron`?

Comment: I make following script:
# /usr/local/bin/update-system.sh
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt autoremove -y